# PC817 voltage floating

Tags: dc-dc-converter, opto-isolator, short-circuit

[image]

I'm using a optical coupler (pc817) to transmission my Digital signal,i can measure  stable voltage on pin 1 , But I do not understand why the voltage on pin 2 is floating ,and it will cause my output voltage be floating , is there anything i make wrong ?

Digital signal: 2-4 V

R1 : 120 ohm

Vcc : 15V

R2 : 1K ohm

Comment: *But I do not understand why the voltage on pin 2 is floating* Pin 2 isn't floating, you connected it to ground so it will be 0 V (zero Volt) relative to that ground.

Comment: i'm sorry, i updated the new sketch

Comment: Pin 2 will have a voltage on it if the analog signal is over 1.05 volts, the turn-on voltage for infra-red LED's, like the one inside your opto-coupler.

Answer (score 2):

It is really hard for me to guess what is the reason you are seeing a problem other than not connecting the circuit or the measurement device up correctly. But let's just assume for a moment that the circuit that you have is like the schematic. You may be able to achieve an analogue in to analogue out transfer function for the circuit but you will have a horrible result. The transfer function will vary from part to part, will change over temperature, and may very well not be linear.

Optocouplers like this are really meant to be used to transfer digital signals that can drive the input diode between two current level states that are well beyond the thresholds needed to turn the output transistor on and off.

Answer (score 1):

If pin 2 is floating, then there is a break in the connections between it and ground.  The resistor keeps the pin from floating when everything is connected as shown in the schematic.

To find the break, keep probing closer to the ground connection until you find the fault.  Put the probe physically on the top end of the resistor and see if that is floating.  What about the bottom end.  You should be able to find the two points between which there is no continuity.

Nothing you do on the input side of the opto-isolator has anything to do with the output side floating.  Actually, the output always floats relative to the input.  That's the point of a opto-isolator.  In this case, the output circuit is tied to the same ground as the input, so won't be floating relative to the input.

This also brings up the question what the point of the opto-isolator is, if you're going to connect the circuits on both sides to the same ground.  It seems you just need a direct connection.  Even if you need more current drive, you could use a couple of transistors or a buffer gate.

Answer (score 1):

I feel something may be lost in translation here. You don't have enough current at 2V in to guarantee saturation of the transistor, depending on the *rank* of PC817 you happen to be using. At 2V in, you typically have 6-7mA in so you would need a CTR of more than 200% to guarantee saturation with a 1K resistor.

Below is a typical response of a PC357nt (happened to have a model available for that). The Y-axis is the output voltage and the X-axis is the input voltage.

[image]

Since you're already pretty high current at the input you could increase the load resistor to something like 3K to 5K to get saturation.

I am assuming it's a digital signal. The optoisolator is just acting as a non-inverting high-side switch, changing 0/2V to 0/15V.

If you actually want to accurately transfer an **analog** signal you will need a much more complex circuit or a part designed specifically for that purpose.